# How to run one Azure Automation runbook for all subscriptions in same tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

How can we run one Azure Automation runbook for all our subscriptions in the same tenant? Currently, I am making use of one runbook which retrieves the resources in the tenant, but it is listing the resources only from one subscription whereas I have 3 subscriptions present.
How do I make sure it outputs all the resources from all subscriptions? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the runbook runs in the security context of an Azure automation account and that account is connected to a subscription and therefore only sees resources within that subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-standalone-account

There is a "Azure management group" which works cross subscription

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview

It may be possible to run the runbook in a context of a management group user that has access to all subscriptions. But I have never tried this so not sure if it would work.

I would suggest that you install and run the runbook in each subscription. Then combine the contents of each report.

Comment: That would be a tedious job right. Also is it like in order to get the resources, do I need to have Owner access to all Subscriptions?